# Does Facebook allow third party login options on Instant Games?

Tags: facebook, authentication, authorization, facebook-authentication, facebook-instant-games

I am trying to make Facebook Instant Game. We are interested whether or not we can use our own service for authorization instead of standard Facebook authorization.

Mainly, I have 2 questions:

1. Can user play if they are not logged into Facebook at all?
2. If they are logged in, can I use my own server to authorize the user inside the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can user play if they are not logged into Facebook at all?**

Unfortunately it is not possible to play Instant Games without a logged in Facebook account. This is because many of the APIs on the platform rely on an authenticated (e.g. ch

**If they are logged in, can I use my own server to authorize the user inside the app?**

You can authenticate the user on your own server using `getSignedPlayerInfoAsync` and sending an `XMLHttpRequest`/`fetch` payload. You cannot authenticate the user using cookies, however. These are blocked in the Instant Games container to preserve user privacy.